# Sequelize BelongsToMany set foreignKey as primaryKey

Tags: associations, sequelize.js, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have relation N:M between User and Role, also I have association named UserRole, where I am storing few attributes and two foreignKeys: `user_id` and `role_id`. My goal is to set `user_id` in UserRole as primary.

User model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        // attributes
    }, {
        underscored: true,
        hooks: {
           beforeCreate: hashPassword,
           beforeUpdate: hashPassword
        }
    })

    User.associate = ({User, Role, UserRole}) => {
        User.belongsToMany(Role, {
            through: UserRole, 
            foreignKey: {
                name: 'user_id',
                allowNull: false
            }
        })
    }

    return User
}
```

Role model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
        // attributes
    }, {
        underscored: true
    })

    Role.associate = ({Role, User, UserRole}) => {
        Role.belongsToMany(User, {
            through: UserRole, 
            foreignKey: {
                name: 'role_id',
                allowNull: false
            }
        })
    }

    return Role
}
```

UserRole model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const UserRole = sequelize.define('UserRole', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        // rest of attributes
     }, {
         underscored: true
     })

    return UserRole
}
```

If I set it as above, I receive table UserRole with that code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "UserRoles" (
    "id"   SERIAL UNIQUE , 
    "is_valid" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    "assigned_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    "revoked_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Users" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    "role_id" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Roles" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE ("user_id", "role_id"), PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

But that is not my goal. I have tried removing `id` attribute in `UserRole` model and setting this in `User` model:

```
User.belongsToMany(Role, {
    through: UserRole, 
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'user_id',
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    }
})
```

But then I received both `user_id` and `role_id` as PK.
Is there any possibility to set only one of foreign keys as identifying primary key? Or maybe I have not understood N:M associations properly?
Thanks in advance for your help.